# Can you create records using GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

Does GraphQL have the capability of manipulating records (ie. POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE)? If not, does GraphQL need to be coupled with a RESTful API to create/modify records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are called `Mutations`.

https://medium.com/@clayallsopp/your-first-graphql-server-3c766ab4f0a2 has one in its examples.

Answer (score 1):

You got a great introduction to GraphQL and PostgreSQL in this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DNPVqK_woRQ&list=PLmFRacg7hfyY7_bTCjdInHdpB2_H0j9s2

I learned a ton from it. In it, Lee shows how to setup a create mutation and relationships.

It also get a running GraphiQL setup to try queries in.